# Why is "self" being returned in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm following this Ruby tutorial here, and it's talking about Stacks and Queues
http://rubymonk.com/learning/books/4-ruby-primer-ascent/chapters/33-advanced-arrays/lessons/86-stacks-and-queues#solution4117

It gives the following code for a stack

```
class Stack
  def initialize
    @store = Array.new
  end

  def pop
   @store.pop
  end

  def push(element)
    @store.push(element)
    self
  end

  def size
    @store.size
  end
end
```

My question is: Why is it necessary to return "self" in the "push" method, but we do not have to return self in say the pop method? What is the distinction here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is due to difference in use case.

- When you use `push`, you use it with the argument `element`, and you further know that the operation succeeds. Getting back the value of `element` from the method is not useful. Having a return value of `self` makes it more convenient such as allowing chaining of the methods.
- When you use `pop`, in useful cases, you are not sure whether the array has an element in it (otherwise it falis), and what element you get by popping. And getting back the popped value is the purpose of using the method.

In other words, `push` is a "setter/modifyer" method whereas `pop` is a (destructive) "getter" method.

Comment: Thanks this makes perfect sense

Answer (score 7):

[Array#push](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-push) and [Array#pop](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-pop) return different things. The first returns the modified array, while the second returns the popped element.

The reason you might not want to return the modified array is that it breaks encapsulation and exposes the internal state of your object. Still, we would like to chain our push calls (i.e. `Stack.new.push(2).push(5)`), so we return self (of type `Stack`) instead of nil or something else.

Comment: Thanks Julien. So just to clarify then: Why does pop not return "self" as well so that the modified stack is returned? Is there anything wrong with that?

Comment: Well it all depends on what you're trying to do. The example class is a Stack (implemented as a restricted Array), so semantically you want to add vales to the top and pull values off the top. If pop did not return the element, you would have to do something like (elem = stack.peek; stack.pop)

Answer (score 2):

Ruby convention is to return the thing being popped on popping, and the data structure itself on pushing. See how arrays behave.

Comment: Ohhhh okay, I think this answers my question to Julien then. So basically, we *could* return "self" in the pop method -- there's nothing wrong with that, but because standard convention is to return the popped element, that's why we don't return "self" ??

Comment: That's what I believe, yes. The reason why this is the convention, is explained in @sawa's answer above.